# Dropdown not binding Inside Ajax Update panel

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I am using the below code to populate a dropdown on a selection of another dropdown.
But somehow, ddlSubTypes is not getting populated when a item is selected in ddlTypes

On selectedindex change event of ddlTypes, i am binding ddlSubTypes.

```
<tr>
    <td class="style3">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scma" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTypes" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTypes_SelectedIndexChanged1">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="style3">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP2" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubTypes" runat="server" Width="200px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
</tr>



Protected Sub ddlTypes_SelectedIndexChanged1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlTypes.SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            'Populate schemes
            ddlSubTypes.Items.Clear()
            Dim ID As Integer = ddlTypes.SelectedValue
            Dim dt As DataTable = IterateSubtypesContents(ID)

            ddlSubTypes.DataTextField = dt.Columns("Type").ToString()
            ddlSubTypes.DataValueField = dt.Columns("ID").ToString()
            ddlSubTypes.DataSource = dt
            ddlSubTypes.DataBind()

            UP2.Update()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: why you have placed two separated update panels ? Instead of placing in the <td> tag place the whole <table> in the updatepanel if possible.

Comment: @WaqarJanjua Yes i did that first. I was having both the dropdowns in single update panel. But it doesent work too.

Comment: ok try this: place an asynpostbacktrigger in the second updatepanel (UP2) and and set it's control ID to ddlTypes and don't call the UP2.Update method in code behind.

Comment: Maybe you're populating ddlTypes in any postback?

Comment: and also move your script manager out of table. No need to place it in a table td tag.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a trigger to the second update panel that gets triggered on the first dropdown's selectedIndexChanged event.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP2" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubTypes" runat="server" Width="200px">
    </asp:DropDownList>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Control That Triggers this Panel" EventName="Desired Event that triggers" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: i am getting this error : Could not find an event named 'ddlTypes_SelectedIndexChanged1' on associated control 'ddlTypes' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UP2'.

Comment: well you have to create the event server side. right now the trigger can't find an event that is handled server side.

Comment: Create an event !!! I just put the selectedindexchange event name of my first dropdown to the EvenName of my second dropdwon. wrong is it ?

Comment: in your code behind page is there an event with the name that you are using in the trigger? that's the error you are getting